# Assign page attributes to postscript file generated in Java using HP Universal Printing PS

Tags: java, pdf, postscript

I am trying to generate postscript file with paper size 7 * 8.5 INCH. I am able to generate the postscript file. But the page size is 8.5 * 11 INCH.

I doubt if it is considering the attribute set i am using.

Appreciate any help.

```
// Load the PDF document

PDFPrint pdfPrint = new PDFPrint(pdfFile, null);
File outputFile   = new File (psFile);

PrintSettings ps = new PrintSettings ();
pdfPrint.setPrintSettings(ps);

// Create attribute set to print to a file
HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attrSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attrSet.add (new Destination (outputFile.toURI()));
attrSet.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);

attrSet.add(new MediaPrintableArea((float)0,(float) 0,(float)7,(float)8.5,MediaPrintableArea.INCH));            

//Send the PDF to the printer                                                 
pdfPrint.print("HP Universal Printing PS", ps, attrSet);
```

Thanks,
Siri

Comment: It would help if you specified which framework you are using. The only mention I can find of a class `pdfPrint` is in the [Qoppa jPDFPrint library](http://www.qoppa.com/pdfprint/guide/guide.html). Here is [com.quoppa.PDFPrint class documentation](http://www.qoppa.com/pdfprint/guide/javadoc/index.html). Is that what you mean? Adding tag "PDF".